# How to insert DATA into Mysql with LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, web-scraping

I am facing some migrate trouble about inserting data with laravel. I am getting the following error:

> ErrorException: Uninitialized string offset: 16

I don't understand why, here is my code:

```
//above is curl codes with no problem there

$veri = curl_exec($curl); 

preg_match_all('@cassette-header">(.*?)<a href="/(.*?)"@si', $veri, $url);

$say = count($url[2]); 

if($say > 0) {
    for ($i=0; $i<$say; $i++) {
        $link ="https://suumo.jp/".$url[2][$i];

        $address = $veri = file_get_contents($link);

        preg_match_all('@<h1>(.*?)</h1>@si',$address, $bina);
        $name = strip_tags(trim($bina[0][0]));

        preg_match_all('@<span class="l-quickright">(.*?)<span class="l-quickright-item">@si',$address, $adres);
        $addr = strip_tags(trim($link = $adres[0][0])); 

        preg_match_all('@<span class="l-quickright">(.*?)<span class="l-quickright-item">@si',$veri, $genislik);
        $extent = strip_tags(trim($genislik[0][2]));

        preg_match_all('@<td class="detailtable-body">(.*?)</td>@si',$veri, $extentwo);
        $extenttwo = strip_tags(trim($extentwo[0][3]));

        preg_match_all('@<td class="detailtable-body">(.*?)</td>@si',$veri, $fiyat);
        $rent = strip_tags(trim($fiyat[0][4]));

        preg_match_all('@<td class="detailtable-body">(.*?)</td>@si',$veri, $buy);
        $time = strip_tags(trim($buy[0][5]));

        preg_match_all('@<td class="detailtable-body">(.*?)</td>@si',$veri, $buytwo);
        $timetwo = strip_tags(trim($buytwo[0][6]));

        $data[] = [
            'Links'          => $link[$i],
            'Building Names' => $name[$i],
            'Addresses'      => $addr[$i],
            'Rooms'          => $extent[$i],
            'Extents'        => $extenttwo[$i],
            'Rents'          => $rent[$i],
            'Sales Start'    => $time[$i],
            'Move In'        => $timetwo[$i],
        ];
    }
}
DB::table('estates')->insert($data);
```

I am getting "ErrorException  : Uninitialized string offset: 16" error. But i don't understand why? Thank you for helping!

Comment: As far as I can see you create the `$data` array inside the if statement, specifically inside the for loop, and you use it outside the condition, any chance that the `$data` does not exist at this point? Does your table in the DB also matches the keys from the array that you are trying to store? 
Can you give us the error message?

Comment: Actually i put all in the if cycle. but this time getting  "ErrorException  : Uninitialized string offset: 16" error. at line; 'Rooms' => $extent[$i],

Comment: That means that the array $extent does not have 16 items. There is nothing wrong with the Laravel code here. You need to validate the data that you are trying to store, before you use it. You can debug each array and make sure that at all the positions there is a value that can be retrieved.

Comment: Sorry, I am very newbie at this. What do you mean by debug the array. Before using it, do I need to print_r the $extent array or something? Can u be more specific about it?

Comment: Yes, you can print them out in order to see if the element you are trying to access exists.

Comment: Btw, I think that you are trying to access an element from an array when $extent is not even an array but a string.

Comment: array is exist I checked it a couple of times. But I made tables like "$table->string('rooms');" the problem that might be the tables? if it's then what should i do about the tables for an array? I tried "longText" too but still the same.

Comment: if you want to store the rooms as a string separated by comma, you can use the 'implode' function so it will be `implode(', ', $extent[$i]);` this will convert the array to a string and then you can store it in that column.

Comment: it doesn't work too... what option do I have? How can I import an array to database with laravel. what a headache problem this is.

Comment: this is not at all a Laravel problem, just so you know. I really can't help much not having the full scenario in order to reproduce it myself on a local machine. Just trying to help based on the code and the error you gave me. You really need to try line by line, printing out ( if that's easier for you ) and check which line produces the error. I cannot see your database nor the input data that you are trying to parse, so can't provide a good solution blindly.

Comment: actually, I think i find the problem and now I am getting this error. "Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string" the problem starts with $addr and keep going.